# MySQL Timestamping

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-web-services, timestamping

I have a table in an Amazon Web Service (AWS) Relation Database Service (RDS) and the table columns are  "Memory", "Cores", "Speed" and "Insert_Timestamp" and I am trying to get the database to log each time a new row is added to this table. With this being said, I am running the following code `Alter table Instace_Types ALTER COLUMN Insert_Timestamp SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I am running into this error:

```
 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN Insert_Timestamp SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1"
```

any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to use `Alter table Instace_Types ALTER COLUMN Insert_Timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: That alter statement may not work depending on your MySQL version. If you cannot alter your table you can always consider supplementing your insert/update query with `insert_timestamp = now()` as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The second `ALTER` should be a `CHANGE`.

```
Alter table Instance_Types 
     CHANGE Insert_Timestamp 
            Insert_Timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```